# JAX-RS CXF: How to get Exception from ResponseExceptionMapper

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs, cxfrs

I have a provider at server to marshall MyException as follows

```
Response.ok(myExceptionObj, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
```

I would like to know how I can implement ResponseExceptionMapper of CXF so that I can get the exception object back.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have used ResponseExceptionMapper to do the job for me.

Comment: This actually not an answer because it does not show us, HOW you used the class to "do the job for you".